# selenium/standalone-chrome:2.53.1: When using this open page is blank

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am using selenium/standalone-chrome-:2.53.1 docker image for nightwatch.conf.js to execute test cases.

Below is the configuration for nightwatch.conf.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const nightwatchCucumber = require('nightwatch-cucumber');
const cucumberConfig = {
    stepDefinitions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'features/step-definitions'),
};

module.exports = {
    src_folders: [nightwatchCucumber(cucumberConfig)],
    output_folder: 'reports',
    custom_commands_path: '',
    custom_assertions_path: '',
    globals_path: '',
    live_output: false,
    page_objects_path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'page-objects'),
    parallel_process_delay: 10,
    disable_colors: false,
    test_workers: false,

    test_settings: {
        default: {
            launch_url: 'any URL',
            selenium_host: 'localhost',
            selenium_port: 4444,
            silent: false,
            disable_colors: true,
            screenshots: {
                enabled: true,
                on_failure: true,
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'screenshots'),

            },
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                chromeOptions: {
                    args: ['--no-sandbox']
                },
                //acceptSslCerts: true,
                //javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
            globals: {
                user: {
                    username: 'user1',
                    password: 'password1',
                },
                hrUser: {
                    username: 'user2',
                    password: 'password2',
                },
            }
        },
```

When I execute test cases, they fail. In console log :

```
Timed out while waiting for element <.AppLoginTest> to be present 
for 5000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"  
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<user>/automation-tests/features/step-definitions/login.js:19:8) 
at next (native)
```

If I execute above test case using normal chrome then it passes.
Problem is coming only with when I run test case using chrome headless browser. 
I do not know why this error is coming with headless browsers? I have even used phantomJS and found same issue.
    Can some one point out what could be the issue?